# Facebook Comments section gets truncated

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, wordpress, plugins

I have an issue with facebook comments on this page of my website: http://www.twisted-perfectionism.com/social-media-network-comparison/

The comment section gets truncated. You can only see 1 comment and a 3/4. There are more coments below, but they don't appear.

What could be the cause of this? I don't get it :(

Please help!

Here is the code from single.php:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="panel box">

    <div class="in">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

            <?php

            $format = get_post_format();
            get_template_part( "formatz/".$format );

            if($format == "")
            get_template_part( "formatz/standard" );
            echo do_shortcode('[shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="xxx"]');
            do_action('seo_facebook_comments');         
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?> 

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `max-height: 206px;` style set on line 159 of your style.css file located in wp-content/themes/selfless/style.css. This prevents the Facebook comments section from being higher than 206px and hence hides any overflow below this height. Deleting this line will show all of your comments.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I hope removing it doesn't break anything else :)

Comment: Please take a look at my other issue. I think you can help me. It would be very much appreciated! Thanks <3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706373/make-footer-scroll-smoothly-in-safari